# training scaler with training data

Tags: python

I'm just confused about training scaler model.

For example,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

object_ss = StandardScaler()

x_train_ss = obje_ss.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_ss = obje_ss.transform(x_test)
```

is this different with the code below?

```
object_ss = StandardScaler()
object_ss.fit(x_train)

x_train_ss = obje_ss.transform(x_train)
x_test_ss = obje_ss.transform(x_test)
```

Comment: There is little meaning in transforming twice

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov oops sorry there is typo

Comment: What I was confused is that
is there difference beween

fit the `Scaler` with `training data` first and transform train set and test set

and

use `fit_transform` to train set, and just `transform` to test set

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The results will be identical, you can verify but trying both approaches and comparing the results.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

object_ss = StandardScaler()
x_train_ss = object_ss.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_ss = object_ss.transform(x_test)

object_ss2 = StandardScaler()
object_ss2.fit(x_train)
x_train_ss2 = object_ss2.transform(x_train)
x_test_ss2 = object_ss2.transform(x_test)

print(np.abs(x_train_ss - x_train_ss2).mean())
print(np.abs(x_test_ss - x_test_ss2).mean())
```

The printed numbers should be very very small (or I would even expect 0 to be printed)

Comment: Thank you so much !! my tutor said that is totally different so I got 0 mark for this..
(I said they are identical)